# I want to slice the data in pandas based on date time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to slice the data based on the date.

If I know what date , I know how to do the slicing. In my case I will NOT the date stamp.
So based on date , I want to do slicing to do my further operation on the data

[image]

Please refer to the example for data. Here date column can have a date of any day. I want slice the data.

*First slice will be for date : 20211201
Second slice will be for date : 20211202*

I am able to covert column into date time format as below

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
df = df.set_index('date')
```

please help over this

Comment: it's not clear what you want , provide desired output as well.

Comment: As you can see in the question I have mention :  First slice will be for date : 20211201
Second slice will be for date : 20211202 .  This is need .But the I may NOT know date to slice by mentioning date

Comment: do you want to have separate df for each month? if yes why? if not explain ( and provide sample output)

Comment: @eshirvana your perfect . But without  mentioning with date to slice as , I will not be knowing date and also there will dates for more than 10years

Comment: It really doesn't matter how big your data is , pandas can handle it , what's the original problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Group by date and find the max in-between time of 9:10 to 9:20 in open column

Comment: now we are getting somewhere.see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you need to do :

```
df = df[df['time'].between('9:10','9:20')].groupby('date')['Open'].max()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Input data

The data you used is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":[20211201,20211201,20211201,20211201,20211201,20211202,20211202,20211202,20211202],\
                    "time":["9:08","9:16","9:17","9:18","9:19","13:08","13:09","13:10","13:11"],\
                    "Open":[17104.4,17105.05,171587.75,17175.2,17168.6,17311.95,17316.5,17322.55,17325.9]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
df = df.set_index('date')
```

### Solution

You can slice the `DataFrame` as follows:

```
import datetime
df1 = df[df.index==datetime.datetime(2021,12,1)]
df2 = df[df.index==datetime.datetime(2021,12,2)]
```

### Output

Then the outputs you would obtain are:

```
>>> df1
            time       Open
date                       
2021-12-01  9:08   17104.40
2021-12-01  9:16   17105.05
2021-12-01  9:17  171587.75
2021-12-01  9:18   17175.20
2021-12-01  9:19   17168.60
>>> df2
             time      Open
date                       
2021-12-02  13:08  17311.95
2021-12-02  13:09  17316.50
2021-12-02  13:10  17322.55
2021-12-02  13:11  17325.90
```

Comment: This is where I have problem. In your solution, you have mentioned the date `2021,12,1`. In my case, there is lots of dates (More than 10 years). I can write for each of date

Comment: Please see update in solution